# Where Do I Go to Change My Password Following the Problems With the Blog Today?

Tags: support, blog

After the blogs were compromised today, it was recommended that users change any shared password for their sites:

> *If you have used the same password on other sites then you should also reset that password on those sites because email addresses and password hashes may have been compromised.*
>   <sub>Kyle Brandt - Lead Systems Administrator - Stack Exchange</sub>

I've been looking for quite a while and I can't find where to go to change my password. I also tried Googling SFF's meta and searching the meta forum, with no luck. I managed to find the password recovery tool, but nothing that a person can use to reset a password.

A little help here? I'd be very grateful. Please and thank you very much :)

Comment: What exactly was compromised?

Answer (score 3):

1. Use the [recovery tool](http://blogoverflow.com/wp-login.php?action=lostpassword)
2. Write user name or or email address
3. Receive an E-Mail
4. Follow the link in the email
5. Choose a new password
6. Type new password again
7. Call it a day.

Comment: Thank you -- that helped a lot. Kyle Brandt's e-mail seemed to suggest changing passwords to all SE sites because the e-mail hashes may have been compromised. Do you know if there's a place to go to change all SE passwords at once, if all your accounts are tied together? Thanks again for a great answer :)

Comment: @Slytherincess It said you should change you password on others account "If you have used the same password". Example, If you use the same password for your twitter account, you should change it. check the "my login" tab in your profile to know which account is used to authenticate you on the stack-exchange network.

Comment: @Slytherincess If you write for blogs on multiple SE sites, those blog accounts are linked. But Blog Overflow is separate from Stack Exchange, so if you were using the same password for both, you need to reset your Stack Exchange password separately, using the "my logins" button on your *network* profile.